# Error in the code from lectures about OO programming in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I was looking at some code from the lectures about OO programming in ocaml. 
This was the code given but it wont work when I compile it. I can't figure out why.

```ml
class point (x_init,y_init) = 
    object (self)
    val mutable x = x_init 
    val mutable y = y_init
     method get_x = x
     method get_y = y
     method moveto (a,b) = x <- a ; y <- b
     method rmoveto (dx,dy) = x <- x + dx ; y <- y + dy
     method to_string () = "(" ^ (string_of_int x) ^ "," ^ (string_of_int y) ^ ")"
    method distance () = sqrt (float(x*x + y*y))
     initializer Printf.printf ">> Creation of point: %s\n" (self#to_string ());
     end ;;
class verbose_point p =
     object (self) 
    inherit point p as super
    method to_string () = "point=" ^ (super#to_string ()) ^ ",distance=" ^ string_of_float (super#distance ())
          initializer Printf.printf ">> Creation of verbose point: %s\n" (self#to_string ())
                end ;;
```

This is the expected result:

```ml
new verbose_point (1,1);;
```

```
>> Creation of point: (1,1)
>> Creation of verbose point: point=(1,1), distance=1.414213- : verbose_point = <obj>
```

but instead I receive this:

```ml
new verbose_point (1,1);;
```

```
>> Creation of point: (1,1), distance=1.414213
>> Creation of verbose point: point=(1,1), distance=1.414213- : verbose_point = <obj>
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a verbose point, so its `self#to_string` method comes from `verbose_point`. This is the essence of late binding.

Comment: In some languages (e.g. beginning with C and ending with +), calling `to_string` within the construction of `point` would call the member function (aka method) from `point`, before moving on to the construction of `verbose_point` on top of it and finally getting access to the definition of `to_string` in `verbose_point`. This might explain OP's confusion.

Comment: "I invented the term 'object oriented', and C++ was not what I had in mind." -- Alan Kay